# Unable to do transaction -ERC 721

Tags: polygon, smartcontracts, metamask, nft, erc721

I'm unable to complete transaction for ERC 721 using Metamask with polygon.this error message is shown when i tryto transact.i'm using this contract.https://github.com/HashLips/solidity_smart_contracts/blob/main/contracts/NFT/NFT.sol
**Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }**

Answer (score 0):

i think your error is on the numbers of mintable, check and see if that helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14895309/chang-kinwai what should I change in below part?mint amount or msg sender?  maxMintAmount = 20;  mint(msg.sender, 20);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://github.com/HashLips/solidity_smart_contracts/blob/main/contracts/NFT/NFT.sol this is contract i used